Repository permanency between stages in an Azure DevOps pipeline
I have an Azure DevOps pipeline with 3 stages in it.
Stage 1: Checkout the self repository. Create folders. Push the changes back to the repo
Stage 2: Checkout the self repository. Create files in the above mentioned folders. Push the changes.
Stage 3: Checkout the self repo. Read the previously created files.
My issue is that even though I push the changes back in Stage 1, when Stage 2 makes the checkout it cannot see these new folders.
So when I run my pipeline it creates the folders, but Stage 2 fails because it cannot see the folders. If I rerun the pipeline the folders are there, so Stage 2 can also succeed, create the files and push them, but Stage 3 won't see these files yet so it will fail. So, I have to run my pipeline 3 times to make it succeed.
It looks like even though the three stages run after one another, and I do separate checkout in all of them, somehow they still download the same initial version of the repository. So even though the checkout of Stage 2 happens after the push of Stage 1, Stage 2 still cannot see the changes made by Stage 1.
Is this a normal behavior? I assumed there are some caching that makes the stages use the same version of the files. If so, is it possible to change this behavior? I don't really have any other idea of what could be the issue here.

I can reproduce the same situation. And I can confirm that this is an expected behavior.
When a pipeline is queued the ref is set. All Stages/jobs in the pipeline will checkout the same reference. This is how Pipeline works.
We can get the ref info in the Pipeline summary Page:


is it possible to change this behavior?

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can directly change this behavior.
For a workaround, you can add git pull or git fetch command in stage to sync the changes in remote azure repo.
For example: git pull origin HEAD:main
- stage: stagename
  jobs:
  - job: 
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true
    - powershell: |
  
       git pull origin HEAD:main
       git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
       git config --global user.name "Your Name"
       xxxx
       git add .
       git commit -m "123"
       git push  origin HEAD:main


I could resolve it with git fetch. It just seemed odd that running the stages one by one on my machine worked, but not when i uploaded the code to devops (so it made the testing harder). But you explained why it works that way and all clear now. thanks

Your pipeline should not be changing the repo. If you need to persist files between stages, use the PublishArtifacts step.
